# Error al conectar a la base de sdatos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo

**me aparece el sigueinte error cuando intento conectar a la base de datos**

**SQLSTATE[42000] [1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'utf8' at line 1**

*esta es la conexion que estoy utilizando*

```
class Conexion{
public static function Conectar(){
    define('server', 'localhost');
    define('name_db', 'crud');
    define('user', 'root');
    define('password', '');

    $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAME utf8');
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".server.";bdname=".name_db, user, password, $opciones);
        return $conexion;
    }catch (Exception $e){
        die("El error de conexion es: ". $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `SET NAMES`, en vez de `NAME `

Comment: Tienes errores de sintaxis cadas 2 lineas revisa que las instrucciones esten bien escritas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pusiste `bdname` para indicar el nombre de la tabla y está mal escrito. Tiene que ser `dbname`, de ***D**ata****B****ase **Name***.

```php
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".server.";bdname=".name_db, user, password, $opciones);
//                                           ^
//                                           |_ Mal escrito
```

Y también `NAMES`:

```php
$opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAME utf8');
//                                                         ^
//                                                         |_ Falta una S
```

**Aparte**

> Por convención, los identificadores de constantes siempre se declaran en mayúsculas.
>
> [Referencias del Lenguaje](https://www.php.net/manual/es/langref.php). [Constantes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php).

Te recomiendo que las constantes siempre las definas en mayúsculas.

Comment: Clarooooooo, no me habia fijado en eso. muchas gracias amigos

Answer (score 0):

El error es el siguiente

```
   $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAME utf8');
```

Cambia por

```
   $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
```

Falta una `S` en la palabra `NAMES`